# Intuition about the rules of integration?

Tags: calculus, integration

It makes complete sense to me that if you want to find the area under a curve you can chop it up into rectangles and as the width of the rectangles approach 0 you can sum them and get the correct area with this equation:
$$lim_{{n \to \infty}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(x)dx$$

My question is how do the rules of integration give me the area. For example how does the upper bound of the integral give me the entire area under the curve up until that point(just exclude the lower bound for now for simplicity) I can't picture how using these rules of integration for the upper bound give me the super tiny rectangles and sums them to give me the area.

Comment: By "the rules of integration" are you referring to the methods of finding an antiderivative?

Comment: @WW1 Yes I don't understand how adding one to the exponent and dividing by the new when plugging in the upper bound gives me the sum of all rectangles

Comment: just referencing a integration technique for a simple example

Comment: @Stef: That, and how, those areas can be computed by such antiderivatives is nothing less than the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus). That's not a trivial statement you or anyone is expected to see "intuitively" on first or second glance. It took me years to grasp its full meaning.

Answer (score 1):

The formula you wrote down isn't very meaningful until you have defined what $f(x)\mathrm{d}x$ means. A more precise definition of the integral might resemble: $$\int_a^bf(x)\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^nf\left(a+\frac{(b-a)k}n\right)\cdot\frac1n.$$It is easier to gain an intuition from this starting point: $a+\frac{(b-a)k}n$ is the horizontal position of the $k$th rectangle we draw between $a$ and $b$, and $\frac1n$, which tends to zero, is the width of the rectangle we are measuring. As a simple example, $$\int_0^1x\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}n\cdot\frac1n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac12n(n+1)}{n^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac12+\frac1{2n}=\frac12$$(which is the same result as you would obtain using the power rule and evaluating $\frac{x^2}2$ at $0$ and $1$).